# Java - Maps inside a Map or Key Object?

Tags: java

Hi I am having 3 attributes (String) that are needed to identify a certain Object.

What is the better solution:

using a key object as those post by [Pierre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190049/using-two-or-more-objects-as-a-hashmap-key) and [Joachim Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635014/any-disadvantage-to-using-arbitrary-objects-as-map-keys-in-java) like this:

```
public class MyKey{

private String one;
private String two;
private String three;

public MyKey(Sting one,String two, String three){
    this.one=one;
    this.two=two;
    this.three=three;
}

//getter only

@Override
public int hashcode(){
// creating Hashcode
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
// comparing
}
}
```

=> `Map<MyKey, Object>`

or using a Map inside a Map inside a Map:

=> `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>`

Comment: Have you tried both? Which one did feel more comfortable?

Comment: Of course the first way is better. You should never go deeper than two levels when it comes to nesting in generic parameter types.

Comment: @Rohit - never ? Ever ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should go with the first option. Reason being that it is more clean and flexible. Imagine a few months down the line you need to add an extra element to your key, your structure would now be invalid since it requires one more level of nesting, not to mention making it more complex.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the key class as you have specified. It's much clearer and has the advantage of being able to name the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You said

> I am having 3 attributes (String) that are needed to identify a
>   certain Object.

That immediately indicates to me that your key consists of three strings, and your first solution is correct and intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you always need the 3 keys you should use a key object (tuple-3) for performance reasons. One object to rule them all...
Also make each key field final if you want better concurrency (you could even pre-compute the hash...)

Answer (score 0):

just implement equals

```
one.equals(o) || two.equals(o) || three.equals(o)
```

and hashcode

```
one.hashCode() ^ two.hashCode() ^ three.hashCode()
```