# Get method of an hashmap with key as another hashmap always returns null values

Tags: java

I have two hashmaps. Each of those have keys as other hashmaps like the one below.

```
Map<Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>>
```

This map gets filled from values of a DB2 database query output. I have noticed that even when I have two such hashmaps and if I try to retrieve the value for a hashmap key, it always returns me null. I have checked by adding all the needed variables in watch window. Everything looks good to me.

Small snippet of my code.

```
mapTransactionNumberTranIds
                .put(inputMessageDbRecord
                        .get(i)
                        .get(prop.getProperty(
                                BloombergConstants.INPUT_BBR_TRANS_NO).toString())
                        .toString(),
                        inputMessageDbRecord
                                .get(i)
                                .get(prop.getProperty(
                                        BloombergConstants.TRAN_ID)
                                        .toString()).toString());
```

Note:
    inputMessageDbRecord is of type `List<Map<String, Object>>` and mapTransactionNumberTranIds is of type `Map<Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>>`

Comment: Ever thought about using things like Objects. You know with members, methods and stuff like that?
A HashMap, though powerful, is not the tool to solve every problem.

Comment: Good point. But unfortunately, I am trying to access a method which is written by someone else which requires input in the above hashmap format only.

Comment: You have create the same HashMap containing the same mapping, meaning the same entryset to pass it on the get() method to obtain the value. It is possible that something is missed when you do that.

Comment: Is it? How can I do this? I am executing same query with a different where clause and getting two result set and then storing that info in the above hashmap. column names in both the result will be the same. I am not using entrySet, I simply check if a given key exists in both hashmap and then do a simple equality comparision.

Comment: `I am trying to access a method which is written by someone else which requires input in the above hashmap format only` This is the point I'd slap the guy with something heavy, to get some attention, and then slap him again not to forget being downright stupid is bad for one's health. Seriously.

Comment: Mansoor, are you able to refactor the method you are calling? Even though equals() is defined in `AbstractMap`, using a HashMap as a key almost looks like an anti-pattern to me. At the very least it could be horribly inefficient...

Comment: Using a HashMap as a key for a HashMap?! This is comical.

Answer (score 2):

You also have to understand that the key will only work if you have the exact same object instance for adding and retrieving from the map and the key is not allowed to never change, because comparison will check if the key is the same instance using equals() and hashCode().

[This article describes issues about using object as key in a hashmap.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635014/any-disadvantage-to-using-arbitrary-objects-as-map-keys-in-java)

Most likely, the problem you are facing is related to those requirements.